# Order on basis of multiple columns

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Suppose I have table project which has following fields:

- number of issue
- number of comments
- number of followers
- created_at

I want to sort project on basis of all the fields, however each field has different precedence. A project with higher issue should be higher up even if it has lesser number of comments or followers. 
Assume order of precedence to be:
issue > followers > comments > created_at

I can't use something like:

```
Select * from Projects ORDER BY Issue, Followers, Comments, Created_at
```

This would first order by issues and then solve conflicts on basis of followers and so on. For ex: I would want a project with 5 issues and 10 comments to be placed lower than one with 3 issues but 50 comments.

I guess I would need to use some multiplicative factor to scale everything in proportion. However, I can't figure out details.

Assume: 1 issue = 2 followers = 4 comments = 1 week old created at time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
Select * from Projects
ORDER BY Issue * 5 + Followers * 3 + Comments DESC, Created_at
```

Comment: Don't forget to make it desc because now you would get your field that has 0 for all values first also you would still need to figure out how to get the values in weeks between now and created_at

Comment: I guess I should have tried the obvious query. However, I am concerned about length of query. Actually, I had posted the simpler version of my problem, those fields are in different tables which are related with project.id. So only for two fields my query looks like: `@projects = Project.joins("INNER JOIN comments ON comments.project_id = projects.id INNER JOIN issues on projects.id = issues.project_id")
        .group("projects.id")
        .order("count(issues.project_id)*5+count(comments.project_id) *3 desc")`